# VB code for batch file creation and execution not working

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, file-io

I'm working on some VB code  that creates a batch file, starts that batch file, then deletes the file. Everything works fine until the file delete part.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test.bat", "@echoe off & start firefox http://www.mixedmartialarts.com http://news.google.com/ & exit", True)
Shell("C:\test.bat", AppWinStyle.Hide)
Kill("C:\test.bat")
```

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - it's very hard to help you if you don't tell us what happens...

Comment: probably because the shell is not finished yet since it needs to start firefox. you may have to wait for some time, then kill the file.

Comment: how would i do that urleader?

Comment: Don't do this.  Use the Process class to start programs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a new thread to continuously check if cmd.exe is running using a while statement. When cmd.exe is no longer running delete the batch file.

Also the best way to open a url is Process.Start("http://www.url.com")